# How do I put the contents of one div above the neighboring one?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

[image: example]

I have 2 div's. The first and second columns are as shown in the figure
On the first column there is a button that shows the third Div: pop-up
On the first column, there is an overflow-y: auto in the code;
It is there because the first column needs a vertical scroll (a lot of information)
If you remove it, the priest does not go down the second column
But, this is not possible, because the possibility of scrolling will be lost
I tried to solve the problem like this

**The first column**

```
height: calc(100vh - 80px);
padding: 20px 5px;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
overflow-y: auto;
```

**The second column**

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 10px;
padding: 17px 0 20px 0;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
overflow-y: auto;
```

**Pop-up**

```
position: absolute;
top: -5px;
left: calc(100% + 5px);
z-index: 999;
```

Comment: Please include your markup ( HTML ) .. Also can you make it clear what do you need ?

Comment: @Sanmeet The code is too big to post here, I need to put a pop-up above the second column

Comment: For making the scroll only in y-axis we just need to add property overflow-y : scroll and to prevent scroll in x-axis overflow-x: hidden..

To create responsive layouts in single direction we use flexboxes ( or grid - for 2 directional layout)... Checkout this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6u0eaxc5/) it might help you